# Filter by Date with VBA code, Filter with range needed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list with Dates and stuff and need to filter them by the Date.

I have this Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim dDate As Date
Dim strDate As String
Dim lDate As Long


dDate = DateSerial(2015, 9, 9)
lDate = dDate
Sheets("Einfügen_Auswertung").Range("A18").AutoFilter
Sheets("Einfügen_Auswertung").Range("A18").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & lDate, _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & lDate + 1


End Sub
```

The Problem is I need a Date in `DateSerial(2015, 9, 9)` that comes from D4. Can someone tell me please how? .Range("D4") isn't working ):

I'm not a programmer... :)
greets

Comment: What does ".Range("D4") isn't working" mean? How are you using `.Range("D4")`? Which error is thrown? Which wrong value occurs where?

Comment: I tried this...dDate = DateSerial.Range("D4")...
I thought this can'T work...

It says compile error or something like this, i have a german version of excel.

Comment: If `ActiveSheet.Range("D4")` contains a date at all, then `dDate = ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value` should work.

Comment: Thank you very much!  it's working!